# Firefox 4: How does File.url work?

Tags: firefox

Did it as stated at [this page](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/07/firefox-4-formdata-and-the-new-file-url-object/comment-page-1/#comment-269140), but got undefined in my Firefox 4 Beta 7.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function read(files) {
 var myFile = files[0];
 document.write(myFile.url);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="file" onchange="read(this.files);" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) will be more useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't working in the current beta. I don't think the standard is very stable yet, so file.url might have been removed since the article was written. I can't find anything about it in [the current API draft](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).

It seems you get the same type of url in FF 4 beta 7 if you use `createBlobURL(myFile)` instead of `myFile.url`